# How can I get taglib >= 1.9

Tags: 22.04, compiling, ardour

I Try to build ardour 8.2 for sources but get a error when I run `./waf configure`.
I get the message "taglib 1.9 not found". I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
When I try to build ardour 7.3, I get the same error.
How do get taglib 1.9 for my Ubuntu release?

Comment: you have another problem. taglib1.9 is from Ubuntu 15.10 so dead https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/taglib/1.9.1-2.1ubuntu2  we are on 2.1 ...

Comment: @Rinzwind. Thank you. I do not yet have a problem. Your link helped me to install necessary packages for taglib. No waf configure does not fail anymore on taglib.